# Convert xml to csv using java sax parser

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am new to java sax parser and i have googled some code. However, it seems none of them are able to convert to csv. Moreover, i have the dtd with me but would it be important to hardcode the dtd elements into a switch case statement.

I am trying to convert the dblp xml to csv

Comment: A SAX parser just gives you callbacks when it encounters elements, tags, and other components of your source document.  It is up to you to write out data.  Are you hoping that a Java library had a built-in XML to CSV converter?  Or are you asking how to do this?

Comment: @RayToal i am asking how to do this

Comment: How would one convert arbitrary XML to CSV?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "pure SAX" approach then capture the data on the end element events for the components, then write out a line on the end element event for the "row".

For example, given

```
<As>
  <A><x>1</x><y>2</y></A>
  <A><x>1</x><y>2</y></A>
  <A><x>1</x><y>2</y></A>
</As>
```

Each time you get a startA event, make an empty array.  On endX and endY events, populate the array.  On your endA event, write out the row.

Please use a CSV library like opencsv to write out the CSV.  You don't want to be messing with quotes and escaping and all that.  It is a solved problem.